how can select many items by don't close FormControl in MUI
const MonthPicker = ({ monthsList, selectedMonths, setSelectedMonths }) => {`


!      main function for select items
const handleChange = (event) => {
const {
target: { value },
} = event;

  setSelectedMonths(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
};

const MenuProps = {
  // Prevent the menu from closing when selecting a menu item
  MenuProps: {
    disableAutoFocusItem: true,
  },
};

 return (
  <FormControl
    sx={{width: "100%",
      "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
        fontSize: "1rem",
        color: Colors.dark,
      },
      "& .MuiSelect-root": {
        fontSize: "0.8rem",
      },
    }}
       size="small">
      <InputLabel id="month-picker-label">Oyni Tanlash</InputLabel>
      <Select
      multiple
      labelId="month-picker-label"
      id="month-picker"
      value={selectedMonths}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Oyni Tanlash" />}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}>
      {monthsList.map((month) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={month.id}
          value={month.name}
          sx={{
            padding: "4px 8px",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            gap: "8px",}}
          // Prevent the menu from closing when clicking on a menu item
          onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={selectedMonths.includes(month.name)}
            sx={{ color: Colors.blue_nbu, padding: 0 }}
            size="small"
          />
          <ListItemText
            primary={month.name}
            sx={{ fontSize: "0.8rem", margin: 0 }}
          />
        </MenuItem>
        ))}
       </Select>
     </FormControl>
   );
`};

i use own function of mui component but can not fix bug , my code works : user select month name and form send item name to array immediately , but i will make collect all of elected month names and send array after selection
